# Block direct pushes to branch

Tags: gerrit

My team uses both gerrit and gitlab and this sometimes causes issues when people are working on both gerrit and gitlab at same time.

While working on gerrit instead of

`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` we wrongly issue `git push`.

So instead of creating a changeset, the code gets automatically pushed to Remote branch.

How can we block all direct pushes to a branch in gerrit?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

```
Gerrit > All-Projects project > Access
```

Look at the "Push" permission at the "refs/heads/*" category. Probably your team has an "ALLOW" in this permission. Edit the project permissions to remove it or to add a "BLOCK" specific for your team.

Answer (score 0):

there is an access category - `push`
so this can be disabled for a group under the project admin site. more info can be found [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push)